# How to add alias for localhost + port?

Tags: localhost, port

I want to hit `127.0.0.1:3000` locally with the alias `local.abc.com`, I have added an entry to etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    local.abc.com
```

so I hit `local.abc.com:3000` and I get the requested page, but is there a way where I don't need to specify the port and just the alias `local.abc.com` translates to `127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: Not using the hosts file.

Comment: @PepitoSh can you elaborate?

Comment: hosts is only for name resolution to IP addresses. In theory you could use SRV records in the DNS system to achieve what you wish, however browsers couldn't care less about that setting.

Comment: One dirt workaround could be serve your web pages on port 80, the default one, chosen when you hit an URL